# angular and socket.io user login

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io

I'm using angular with socket.io and express on the backend (redis/mongodb).

What's the easiest way to validate a user's password and log them into my app?

I haven't written any code for to handle this yet. but I keep seeing 10 different ways, some using sessions (which I think don't apply here since sockets+singlepage app).

If passport.js is easy to implement I'm fine with that solution. I only care about IE9+

Comment: Passport is easy and I have used it. But it is used at the node application side. If your application is a single page application then you require to save and manage the authenticated user's credentials at the front end (client) too.

Comment: I haven't found any good examples on how to do this with sockets

Comment: I haven't tried sockets yet. I am thinking of trying it in my next app.

Comment: from what i understand, you have to use two different session stores. One for express/REST api and a different one for sockets. And you need to associate them somehow. I think I'll stick to REST for authenticated for now and use sockets for unauthenticated realtime events.